# html2canvas works in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html2canvas

I am capturing the screenshot of the Scorm content present inside the iframe, I am getting screenshot in the firefox but not in chrome, it seems like issue is with images path/url while rendering into the canvas.
 I have compared the result of `logging: true` from both browser.
 And I found that images path in the chrome is changed that's why it is not working in chrome.
**How can i solve this? help me........**

```
var iframeEle = document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.body;//working

console.log(iframeEle);

// $('#saveReport').on('click', function(){
    html2canvas(iframeEle, {
        //background: '#fff',
       // height: window.innerHeight,
        //windowHeight: window.innerHeight,
        logging: true,
       
        onrendered: function(canvas){
            // before_imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            before_imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        }
    });
```

**Log for firefox browser :**
when I checked path of images for rendering it is correct.
[image]

**Log for chrome browser :**
in chrome the path for images is not right as it consist of current url of browser thats why is not capturing correctly.
I think it is issue of relative path for chrome and not for firefox.

[image]